# How can I avoid writing repetitive code in javascript for my Tic-Tac-Toe game?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a game of Tic-Tac-Toe in html using javascript. I am at the beginning but I have tried a lot of stuff but i can't seem to make this code shorter an not repetitive. This is only a snippet of the code.

```
var turn = true;

function place1(){
 if(turn == true){
  xb1();
 } else{
  ob1();
 }
 b1.removeEventListener("click", place1);
}

function xb1(){
 b1.classList.add("x");
 console.log(turn);
 turn = !turn;
}

function ob1(){
 b1.classList.add("o");
 console.log(turn);
 turn = !turn;
}

var b1 = document.querySelector("#b1");
b1.addEventListener("click", place1);




function place2(){
 if(turn == true){
  xb2();
 } else{
  ob2();
 }
 b2.removeEventListener("click", place2);
}

function xb2(){
 b2.classList.add("x");
 console.log(turn);
 turn = !turn;
}

function ob2(){
 b2.classList.add("o");
 console.log(turn);
 turn = !turn;
}

var b2 = document.querySelector("#b2");
b2.addEventListener("click", place2);
```

Comment: one question.. repetitive *HOW*?

Comment: There are similar functions. One to place an "X", one to place an "0", and the "place" function itself.  I want to have only 3 functions that i can use and not 27 for each box (9 boxex with 3 functions each).

Comment: Hey alin, this is quite a complex task for somebody who is new and your not wanting to repeat code is understandable. The following link which I found through a google search for Javascript tic tac toe will help you massively and if you read through the code and explanations I think will help you understand a lot more. https://dev.to/bornasepic/pure-and-simple-tic-tac-toe-with-javascript-4pgn

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not an answer to how you could make the game, but try the functional programming approach, also learn to write clean code, name your functions in such a way that it can explain what it does. Also before trying to code it, make a list with all the functionality your game should have.
Example :

- For a Tic-Tac-Toe you can have a function that assign a value to the
  square you clicked on.
- You should have a function that checks if someone won.
- You should store your data somewhere and when something changes there should be some functions to run.
- etc.
  Hope I helped you somehow.

Comment: Agree with your answer, but examples or links would greatly improve these suggestions.